# Elementor: How to override global theme style settings?

Tags: plugins, theme-options, design

When I set the global settings for a link, I'm not able to overwrite Titles with a link.

Here is an example:

```
<h3 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
   <a href="http://example.com">My Homepage</a>
</h3>
```

Because of the `<a>` tag, it changes my font of the `<h3>` tag. If I go manually to the element, I cannot change its style, because the `<a>` is always prefered.

How can I overwrite an element above the global theme settings?

Answer (score 2):

I would change the CSS for that particular heading. Sth like this might help:

```
h3.elementor-heading-title > a {
  copy style of .elementor-heading-title here;
}
```

If you have trouble finding the style in question, just ask here. :)